# JSF2 + GlassFish3: моя первая параметризованная страница

Tags: java-ee, jsf, java

Это мой первый веб-проект - не могу разобраться. У меня есть иерархия узлов

```
@ManagedBean
class Node{
    public String getCurrentNode();
    public void setCurrentNode(String node);
    public List<String> getChildNodes();
    public String getParentNode();
}
```

Как правильно нарисовать node.xhtml для него c работающими ссылками на родителя и всех детей?

Comment: Вид страницы нужен самый простой (без деревьев) типа: ссылкаНаРодителя ссылкаНаПервенца ссылкаНаСледующего иТд

Comment: Я так понимаю, очень похоже на интернет книгу, где снизу или сверху страницы ссылки на предыдущую страницу, на следующую и на оглавление?

Comment: Да. Примерно так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал примерно так:

```
<html ...>
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{node.currentNode}" />
</f:metadata>
<h:head>
    <title>Node</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:link value="#{node.parentNode}" outcome="node">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{node.parentNode}" />
    </h:link>
    <h:dataTable var="child"
                 value="#{node.childNodes}"
                 rules="all"
                 cellpadding="5">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Child" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:link value="#{child}" outcome="node">
                <f:param name="id" value="#{child}" />
            </h:link>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как интересно. Что же все-таки сделать то надо было?

Answer (score 1):

Очень Вам советую использовать [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces). Вы не особо много времени потратите на изучение, но зато Вам не придется изобретать велосипеды снова и снова. RichFaces очень замечательно срабатывается с JSF2. Там уже до вас сделаны все основные примочки и удобства дизайна, в том числе и деревья.

Конечно, не ответил конкретно но, надеюсь, помог. [Вот](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/#richTrees) конкретная ссылка на описание деревьев в RichFaces.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Только мне пока не нужны деревья на странице. Мне не удается нарисовать обычную ссылку (активную строку текста).

Comment: <h: commandLink .......>
Пробовали так?

Comment: Мне нужен код всей страницы

Answer (score 1):

Значит надо примерно так.

Если есть список страниц 1.xhtml, 2.xhtml, 3.xhtml ... Дальше, если Ваш класс `Node` будет своими методами указывать на данные страницы в зависимости от текущей, то сделать можно примерно так (для `Tomcat`): надо установить бин в сессионный `@SessionScoped` (написать после `@ManagedBean`) и на странице написать, например следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        >
<h:head>
    <title>Добро пожаловать</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:panelGroup id="include">
        <ui:include id="iii" src="#{Node.page}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <!--
        Дальше мы делаем ссылки, 
        при помощи которых изменится в классе Node переменная page, 
        и после перезагрузки страницы,
        <ui:include id="iii" src="#{Node.page}"/> 
        будет указывать на новую страницу, которая и должна загрузиться
    -->

    <!-- Происходит вызов функции, которая меняет в классе переменную page -->
    <h:commandButton value="Результаты ДТ" action="#{Node.parentNode}" />

    <!-- Ну и аналогичные кнопки на другие функции. -->
</h:body>
</html>
```

В то же время, в классе есть функция `getPage()`:

```
String getPage(){
    return page;
}
```

Страница по данной методике в Томкате работает, а вот если в GlassFish, то там, наверное, надо немного по-другому. В JSF2 facelets, которые подгружают шаблоны других страниц на текущую, по моему мнению, как-то сложноваты для новичка, если делать все по правилам и красиво.

PS: С разметкой хорошей я не старался. И если как-то все равно не так ответил, то значит можно и по-подробнее описать задачу.

Answer (score 1):

огромное спасибо за активное участие. видать внятное изложение проблемы - не мой конек. на других форумах никто даже не притронулся. ManagedBean - он MODEL и ничего не знает о VIEW и CONTROLLER, значит в нем нет ссылок на страницы представления. Для определенного вида материала(который как раз он MODELирует), он знает что необходимо для того чтобы получить возможность управлять им и отображать его. Например вот как выглядит это же решение для страницы чтения книг:

```
@ManagedBean
class BookPage {
 String getBook() // это штрих-код книги
 void setBook(String book) // чтобы контроллер мог назначить книгу
 int getPage() // это номер страницы из книги
 void setPage(int page) // чтобы контроллер мог листать страницы
 String getText() // для VIEW что-бы он знал что написано на этой странице книги
}
```

где-то внутри этот класс вызывает что-то типа
`SELECT Text FROM BookPages WHERE Book=?Book AND Page=?Page;`
он не `SessionScoped` потому-что ему не надо никаких параметров кроме `Book` и `Page`
а они и так на странице болтаются.

bookpage.xhtml:

```
<html ...>
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="book" value="#{bookPage.book}" />
    <f:viewParam name="page" value="#{bookPage.page}" />
</f:metadata>
<h:head>
    <title>BookPage</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="#{bookPage.book}" /><br/>
    <h:outputText value="#{bookPage.text}" /><br/>
    <h:outputText value="#{bookPage.page}" /><br/>
    <h:link value="предыдущая страница" outcome="bookpage">
        <f:param name="book" value="#{bookPage.book}" />
        <f:param name="page" value="#{bookPage.page-1}" />
    </h:link>
    <h:link value="следующая страница" outcome="bookpage">
        <f:param name="book" value="#{bookPage.book}" />
        <f:param name="page" value="#{bookPage.page+1}" />
    </h:link>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну, Вы замечательно быстро освоили JSF )))